# Getting template type from inherited class C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

So I'm trying to populate a custom collection of a class that is inherited from a template class, like so

```
template<typename T>
class Parent {
public: 
  T value;
  Parent(T val) {value = val;}
}

class ChildA : Parent<int> {
... 
}

class ChildB : Parent<double> {
...
}

// ==== Collections ====
template<typename cT>
class ParentCollection {
public:
  cT list[10];
}

class ACollection : ParentCollection<ChildA> {
...
}

class BCollection : ParentCollection<ChildB> {
...
}
```

So I want to add a function to ParentCollection that will allow me to generate and add a new cT type the the list array. This should be inherited by the children. If I was to write this in ACollection or BCollection, it would be something like:

```
void ACollection::Add(int val) {...}
```

or

```
void BCollection::Add(double val) {...}
```

respectively. However, since these both do the exact same thing except generate different Childrens, I would want to write this in the ParentCollection, but I can't figure out how to do something like:

```
void ParentCollection::Add(T val) {...}
```

that is, use the T type from the Parent class template in the parms for ParentCollection. Is something like this possible? Or must I write the add functions separately for both child collections.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `void ACollection::Add(ChildA val) {...}`?  Is the member of Collection supposed to be `cT list[10];`?  Is `ChildA` supposed to be privately inheriting from `Parent`?  Is ParentCollection tightly bound (programmatically) to Parent -- i.e, ParentCollection relies on and knows about things in Parent?

Comment: @Eljay  I fixed the cT a minute before your comment. Sorry about that. And no, because I want the ACollection to be responsible to handling the initialization of the ChildA class, I just need to give ACollection the required constructor params to Add. ParentCollection knows about parent and handles some shared members of childrens in parent. Like it will have a `SetActive(T val)` that will set a bool in Parent to true. But again, still figuring out how to get the T of Parent to ParentCollection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually it's a good idea to expose the template parameters, because since C++ has no reflection capabilities it's otherwise a hassle to obtain them outside of the class itself:

```
// inside parent class
using value_type = T;
```

You can then reference this typedef to specify your member function signature:

```
void Add(typename cT::value_type val)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can typedef the T type in the parent class and then use it in a derived class:

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
  public:
    typedef T BaseT;
};

class Derived : public Base<int>
{
  public:
    static void printBaseType()
    {
      printf("%s\n", typeid(BaseT).name()); // prints "i"
    }
};
```

---

Specific instructions for fixing this:

- In the Parent class, add: typedef T ParentT
- You can then use the type ChildA::ParentT (int) or ChildB::ParentT (double)
- In the ParentCollection class, you can expose this again by doing: typedef typename cT::ParentT ParentT
- In ACollection, you can then access it as ParentT.
- In ParentCollection, you can write the function declaration as: void Add(ParentT val);
- The function definition, however, needs to qualify the ParentT type because you are outside of the class scope, so you write: void ParentCollection::Add(ParentCollection::ParentT val) { ... }

Comment: I'm confused, this doesn't seem to allow me to do something like `Add(typeid(BaseT) val)` does it?

Comment: No, since typeid(BaseT) is not itself a type. You want to use the BaseT type directly: Add(BaseT val)

Comment: That's fine for allowing the derived class to use. Doesn't seem that useful, since the derived class already knows what type it is itself. How do I add it the the collection of the base class though? I tried `Add(cT.BaseT val)` and `Add(cT::BaseT val) both doesn't seem to work

Comment: cT.BaseT won't work because you can't use that syntax
cT::BaseT won't work because the compiler can't figure out that this is a type. You have to explicitly tell it like this: "typename cT::BaseT"

Comment: Hey thanks. Just commenting to let others know that the new edited instructions works exactly as required. However, I chose the answer from Daniel Jour since it is much simpler (and also seems to work in my scenario? Maybe yours works better in a wider case?) However, your solution is the one I will be using due to some constraints on my projects. Thanks!